# Can I memoize a setter function from a React context (useContext)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use `useEffect` to fetch data when a component is mounted as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(myUrl)
        .then(response => {
            setName(response.name);
            setAge(response.age);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}, [myUrl, setName, setAge]);
```

`setName` and `setAge` are coming from a context as follows:

```
import MyContext from './context';

const MyComponent = props => {
    const {
        setName,
        setAge
    } = useContext(MyContext);
```

This issue is that functions, arrays, and objects all register as "changed" dependencies in a `useEffect` call so it ends up in an infinite loop where it's fetching that data over and over and over again. Can I memoize a function from a context so it knows to only call that effect once?

**Note:** The consumer of my context is several levels above this component so I'm guessing there's nothing I can do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to memoize a function from a context.

That said, you *can* use a custom hook for `useMount`, either by importing it from the [`react-use`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) library or by simply looking at [the source code](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useMount.ts) there and declaring it yourself. The following shows how to define `useMount` and `useEffectOnce` and then utilize `useMount` as a workaround:

```
    const useEffectOnce = (effect) => {
        useEffect(effect, []);
    };

    const useMount = (fn) => {
        useEffectOnce(() => {
            fn();
        });
    };

    useMount(() => {
        axios.get(myUrl)
            .then(response => {
                setName(response.name);
                setAge(response.age);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
```

With this approach, you don't need to change anything about your context declaration, context provider, or context consumer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define [custom context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) tied to something like userId. 
This will provide you a stable identifier which will change only when it is necessary.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean defining a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) based on useContext. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. You need to work with [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to share data (user information in your case) between multiple components. It looks like your case. Personally I am staying away from hooks and use observables from mobx + I prefer OOP React components.